# MySQL join update: Updating join table row twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

To explain the problem I have just outlined an example situation below.

`OrderRows`

```
ID|OrderNumber|ProductNumber|Quantity|Done
1 |10         |100          |1       |no*
2 |10         |101          |1       |no
3 |10         |100          |4       |no*
```

*Have the same product number

```
Stock
ProductNumber|Quantity
100          |5
101          |1

UPDATE OrderRows 
INNER JOIN Stock ON Stock.ProductNumber=OrderRows.ProductNumber 
SET Done='yes'
   ,Stock. Quantity = Stock. Quantity -OrderRows. Quantity 
WHERE OrderNumber='100' AND Done='no'
```

The result for the table `Stock` will be as below.

```
ProductNumber|Quantity
100          |4
101          |0
```

The Order Rows are updated correctly.  But for Order Row three the Stock is not adapted. This is because Order Row three has the same Product Number as Order Row one. The question is, how can I fix this?

Comment: What's your desired output for both tables after the correct update?

Comment: @hims056
`
ID|OrderNumber|ProductNumber|Quantity|Done</br>
1 |10         |100          |1       |yes</br>
2 |10         |101          |1       |yes</br>
3 |10         |100          |4       |yes</br>'

ProductNumber|Quantity</br>
100          |0</br>
101          |0</br>

Comment: @hims056
For all OrderRows Done have to be 'yes' and the stock for Product Number 100 should be 0

Comment: I got the point. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` here. But we can't use it directly. So you can achieve this using sub-query like this:

```
UPDATE OrderRows o
  JOIN Stock s
    ON s.ProductNumber = o.ProductNumber
  JOIN 
     (
       SELECT ProductNumber, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
         FROM OrderRows 
        WHERE  Done = 'no'
        GROUP BY ProductNumber
     ) o1
   ON o.ProductNumber = o1.ProductNumber
  SET o.Done = 'Yes'
     ,s.Quantity = s.Quantity - o1.Quantity
 WHERE o.Done = 'no';
```

Tables after update:

OrderRows

```
| ID | ORDERNUMBER | PRODUCTNUMBER | QUANTITY | DONE |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |          10 |           100 |        1 |  Yes |
|  2 |          10 |           101 |        1 |  Yes |
|  3 |          10 |           100 |        4 |  Yes |
```

Stock

```
| PRODUCTNUMBER | QUANTITY |
----------------------------
|           100 |        0 |
|           101 |        0 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcb29/1)